# Bootstrap Glyphicon not visible

Tags: bootstrap-modal

A very basic question.

Not sure what is the issue.

When I use glyphicon glyphicon-envelope it is visible.

But no other glyphicon is visible. Instead I see only a small box.

Here is my code

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="tile purple parent" id="@item.Id">
            <h3 class="title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentName)</h3>
            <p><span class="glyphicons glyphicon-envelope">@videos.Count()</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could you please help?

Comment: Perhaps a typographical error? I believe the main class `glyphicons` should be `glyphicon` (no s)

Comment: @Wondercricket - Yes thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">@videos.Count()</span>`.

I would recommend you look into Font Awesome http://fontawesome.io/. They have more icons than bootstrap glyphicons.

Answer (score 0):

When i trying your code snippets it works without any problem :)
however you can get more info from `w3school`

[Try your code here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_envelope&stacked=h)

[for more info](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp)

I think problem is in your `bootstrap.min.css` i think file isn't being loaded correctly please relink your boostrap css as follows :)
try to install the glyphicons fonts properly 
 good luck :)

```
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
```

you can also use fontawesome icons  http://fontawesome.io/icons/